# struts2 json regular expression

Tags: json, struts2, jqplot

i want to use jQPlot with Struts, i have a json result output from a struts action like:

```
{
    "jqPlotJSONFormat":
        "['18-03-2010',56],['19-03-2010',43],['17-03-2010',84]"
}
```

but i want to get the data like:

```
['18-03-2010', 56],
['19-03-2010', 43],
['17-03-2010', 84]
```

this is my action mapping :

```
@Action(value="getData", results = {
    @Result(name="success",type = "json", params = {
    "includeProperties","jqPlotJSONFormat"
})})
```

i want to hide the jqPlotJSONFormat in the json result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Set the root object to be the jqPlotJSONFormat](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/json-plugin.html#JSONPlugin-RootObject), roughly (XML version):

```xml
<result type="json">
  <param name="root">
    jqPlotJSONFormat
  </param>
</result>
```

Instead of "includeProperties" in your params, use "root". This declares the root of the JSON object. With "includeProperties" the action is still the root (e.g., properties will be named).

Comment: +1 More specifically in the OPs case changing the params to be: "root", "jqPlotJSONFormat"